# Have truecrypt run script on mount/dismount

Tags: windows-7, mount, truecrypt

Is there a way to have a script automatically triggered when a truecrypt volume is mounted or dismounted? I don't mean a script to actually perform the mount or dismount, I want scripts that can react to truecrypt mounting or dismounting a volume.

Specifically, I've got MySQL databases hosted on a truecrypt volume.  I've got truecrypt setup to dismount when I logout or lock my desktop session, but MySQL doesn't react well to the database disappearing out from under it.  I'd like to have scripts fired on dismount to stop mysqld and start it on mount.

(Windows 7, TrueCrypt 7.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you don't want a script to perform the mounting, but your best bet might be to make a batch script that DOES perform the mounting, but also performs the necessary MySQL commands (same in reverse). Batch scripts triggered by a Truecrypt mounting is beyond my expertise.

Comment: [This](http://draptik.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/executing-a-script-after-mounting-a-truecrypt-partition-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/) works on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoit to make a script that runs a batch file with your changes when it detects logging out or locking your computer.